# User redirect after login, depending on its role in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I have code that changes the role if the user buys a certain product.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'change_role_on_purchase' );
function change_role_on_purchase( $order_id ) {

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_name = $item['name'];
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];

    if ( $order->user_id > 0 && $product_id == '3422, 3423, 3424' ) {
        update_user_meta( $order->user_id, 'paying_customer', 1 );
        $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

        // Remove role
        $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); 

        // Add role
        $user->add_role( 'subscriber' );
    }
}
}
```

I need to, after logging in to the site, if the user "Subscriber" and he has a certain "Subscription" product in the cart, then the system redirects it to the checkout page.

I shall be very glad of your help!

---

**Update:** I will keep this variant. It can help other users.

```
add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3);
function my_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user)
{

global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$ids_to_check = array(3422, 3423, 3424);

foreach ($items as $item => $values) {
$product_id = wc_get_product($values['data']->get_id());

if (in_array($product_id, $id_to_check)) {
    //is there a user to check?
    if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
        //check for subscribers
        if (in_array('subscriber', $user->roles)) {
            // redirect them to another URL, in this case, the homepage
            $url = get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_checkout_page_id'));

            $redirect_to = $url;
        } 
    }

}

}

return $redirect_to;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if statement` will never return true, because you checking the product id if they are equal to  `'3422, 3423, 3424'` which your product will  never  be equal to this what you need to do is store those ids in array and check if the product id in the array and if yes execute your code.

try the following:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'change_role_on_purchase');
function change_role_on_purchase($order_id)
{

    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $ids_to_check = array(3422, 3423, 3424, 15);
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $product_name = $item['name'];
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];


        if (in_array($product_id, $id_to_check) && $order->user_id > 0) {
            update_user_meta($order->user_id, 'paying_customer', 1);
            $user = new WP_User($order->user_id);

            // Remove role
            $user->remove_role('customer');

            // Add role
            $user->add_role('subscriber');

        }

    }

}
```

To redirect  the user if they have certain role you can use the following if you are using Woocommerce login page:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 20, 2);


function my_login_redirect($redirect, $user)
{

    if (in_array('subscriber', $user->roles)) {
        // redirect them to another URL, in this case, the homepage

        $url = get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_checkout_page_id'));

        $redirect = $url;

    }

    return $redirect;

}
```

if you are using WordPress Default login form you can use the following function:

```
add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 20, 3);


function my_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user)
{
    //is there a user to check?
    if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
        //check for subscribers
        if (in_array('subscriber', $user->roles)) {
            // redirect them to another URL, in this case, the homepage
            $url = get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_checkout_page_id'));

            $redirect_to = $url;
        }
    }

    return $redirect_to;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for corrections. Can you help with the redirect?

Comment: yes sure i will write the code for u but it's going to be different hooks

Comment: @Dmitry i added new function to my answer check it and let me know

Comment: Sorry, you can add the third code, only without having certain products in the cart. Just redirect the user to the checkout page if the user is a "Subscriber"?

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that *woocommerce_order_status_processing* does NOT guarantee that the order has been paid for. It simply means what it says. If you change the user role based on an open order, you open yourself to the risk that customers whose payment hasn't gone through do have access to whatever you are offering by changing the user role.